# smartgwt - Leave a column in dynamic form blank

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I created a 3 column dynamic form in smartgwt. now what I want to accomplish is to place form elements in the first and last columns. is there any whay?

PS: I've set `form.setTitleOrientation(TitleOrientation.TOP);` so there are only 3 columns, not 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to play with startRow and endRow, so your first forItem will have setStartRow(true) and setEndRow(false) your third formitem will have its setStartRow(false= and setEndRow(true) in the middle you put a spacerItem.
youFormSetItems(yourFirstItem which start a row, a new SpacerItem instance, your second item which end a row);